# Recursive listing of all files in Groovy with eachFileRecurse return FileNotFoundException

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My `new File` work and contains any xml files but my but `eachFileRecurse` return `java.io.FileNotFoundException`:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/myjob/abcd/TestFlux
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/myjob/abcd/TestFlux
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/myjob/abcd/TestFlux
    at tests_flux.foo(tests_flux.groovy:48)
    at tests_flux$traiter.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at tests_flux.run(tests_flux.groovy:114)
```

This is my code run on Jenkins:

import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES

```
def foo() {
    File f = new File("abcd/TestFlux")
    String currentDir = f.getAbsolutePath()
    println currentDir

    f.eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
        println it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new File()` does not imply the file exists or anything.  It's an holder, that be asked to look into the fileystem for you.  E.g.

```
groovy:000> new File("/hehe/lol")
===> /hehe/lol
groovy:000> new File("/hehe/lol").exists()
===> false
groovy:000> new File("/hehe/lol").isDirectory()
===> false
```